# Detecting TWebModule Memory Leaks

Tags: delphi

I have a Delphi Apache Shared Module.  The base class is TWebModule.  I can run it using the debugger by specifying the following parameters:

**Host Application:** C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\httpd.exe

**Parameters:** -X -w -f "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\httpd.conf"

I believe I may have a memory leak somewhere in my code.  I have tried both EurekaLog and FastMM but haven't been able to get them to detect any leaks let alone do any useful logging.  For FastMM I have defined  **FullDebugMode**.  But when I run no log files are ever created.

I have successfully used Eureka Log to detects leaks for Win32 applications.  But the integration with Apache has proven very difficult.

Can anyone offer strategies/tools for tracking memory leaks for a Apache Dynamic Shared Object?

Comment: Actually experimented more with EurekaLog.  Instead of running it from the debugger I started Apache from the control panel.  And in my Eureka Options I specified the location of the log file.  And this has worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For FastMM4, you have to make sure you defined also :

```
{$define LogMemoryLeakDetailToFile}
{$define EnableMemoryLeakReporting}
```

I would also try without requiring the IDE or debugger be present:

```
{.$define RequireIDEPresenceForLeakReporting}
{.$define RequireDebuggerPresenceForLeakReporting}
```

Make also sure you have debug info turned on or disable:

```
{.$define RequireDebugInfoForLeakReporting}
```